# text file formatting for input to a python plug-in

Tags: python, input, text, formatting

i am attempting to upload a text file via a python based plug-in into an animation program.
the example text file will upload, but the text file i have created will not upload. I do not see how i have formatted MY file differently than the example.
i think there are some "invisible" formatting issues in my file that I am not aware of.
Each value on each line is supposed to be seperated by a 'tab'

In the following/linked forum entry you can see the example (first pasted there) has formatting displayed that mine (2nd pasted there) does not.

Does this mean that the text file i have created is missing something i am not aware of?

https://forums.synfig.org/t/synfig-import-labels-template-problem/8785?u=mzempel

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any correlation between the content the URL refers to and your question.

Comment: Ah. I should have just uploaded the two text files